# onTouchEvent() of Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView never been called in cocos2dx

Tags: android, mouseevent, keyevent, cocos2d-x-2.x

I'm trying to add mouse support with cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.3 on Android platform, however, i met a problem that when i clicked mouse left button, `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView::onTouchEvent()` was never called, but when clicked the right mouse button, `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView::onKeyDown()` was called and the keyCode is `0x04(KEYCODE_BACK)`, it's really strange..

If the `Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView` cannot capture the mouse button click event, i cannot dispatch this event to `Cocos2dxRenderer` which will call the C++ layer functions.

I tried to add the following line in

```
Cocos2dxActivity::init()
{
    ...
    this.mGLSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(mGLSurfaceView);
}
```

however, it doesn't make any sense, my goal is to dispatch the mouse key event to C++ layer, however, the functions in Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView was never called..

any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I also made Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView to implements OnHoverListener, OnClickListener, OnKeyListener, OnTouchListener, however, none of the above funtions is called.